# How do I reference a Module in VB from a NuGet package

Tags: vb.net, webforms, nuget, extension-methods

I've created my own private NuGet server and hosted two packages written in VB, one with a single public class and one with a Module containing some extension methods. When I reference the packages in my application, I am able to create a new instance of the class from the package, but I am unable to use any methods declared in the module. I know that modules need to be contained withing the namespace, so I have a feeling I may need to reference it somewhere to make use of it. Does anyone know what I need to do? Thanks.

I've currently got the following:

```vb
Namespace TestHelperNamespace

    Public Class TestHelper

        Public Sub DoSomething()

        End Sub

    End Class

    Public Module TestModule

        Public Sub StringSub(s As String)

        End Sub

    End Module

End Namespace
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the Module's namespace in your code

```
Imports NugetModuleNamespace
```

Here's a MCVE

```vb
Imports Namespace2

Namespace Namespace1
    Module Module1
        Private Sub foo()
            Dim a = 1.23#
            Dim b = a.Square() ' doesn't work without Imports
        End Sub
    End Module
End Namespace

Namespace Namespace2
    Module Module2
        <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
        Public Function Square(value As Double) As Double
            Return value ^ 2
        End Function
    End Module
End Namespace
```

This applies to Modules in separate files as well.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I'm still struggling to get it to work. I've added more to the question to show what I've got currently in the NuGet package. It will only let me import the namespace for the NuGet module, not the TestHelperNamespace.

Comment: I know this isn't an extension method currently in the example, but it should still be callable to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: @JoshuaBradbury do you have a RootNamespace in the project? What about `Imports RootNamespace.TestHelperNamespace`?